# Breaking it down - simple explanation for regular expressions used in ruby exercise

Tags: ruby, regex

Problem # 1

In this first problem (line 2) - can someone break it down as to what is happening in terms easy for someone new to Ruby regular expressions to understand?

```
 def encode(string)
  string.scan(/(.)(\1*)/).collect do |char, repeat|
   [1 + repeat.length, char]
 end.join
 end
```

Problem # 2

In this second problem (same answer, but different format to solution) - can someone break it down as to what is happening in terms easy for someone new to Ruby to understand?

```
def encode(string)
    string.split( // ).sort.join.gsub(/(.)\1{2,}/) {|s| s.length.to_s + s[0,1] }
end
```

Comment: It's hard to give a simple explanation if you don't specify which part you don't understand.

Comment: try this with your encode method `encode "aaaaaaaaaaaaaa" or encode "ZYXWWW" `

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a "explain how this works" site. Instead, you should try using IRB, Pry, or one of the Ruby debuggers, and pick it apart. Try changing things, and see what happens. As for regular expressions, read through the [Regexp](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Regexp.html) documentation, then use [Rubular](http://rubular.com) to try things.

Comment: @YuHao - I mentioned line two in the first problem ... this part:string.scan(/(.)(\1*)/). , and in the entire second line of the second problem up to the {|s| .. }

Comment: For someone new to regular expressions, it is very helpful for someone more experienced to breakdown what is really happening than just reading over the docs. I've read the docs and experimented but having other people explain is helpful. Some people learn better that way. - @theTinMan

Comment: That is true, however that doesn't make the question on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy for you to break these down and figure out what they're doing. Simply use IRB, PRY or Sublime Text 2 with the "Seeing is Believing" plugin to look at the results of each operation. I'm using the last one for this:

```
def encode(string)
string                     # => "foo"
.scan(/(.)(\1*)/)          # => [["f", ""], ["o", "o"]]
.collect { |char, repeat|
  [
  1 +                      # => 1, 1 <-- these are the results of two passes through the block
  repeat.length,           # => 1, 2 <-- these are the results of two passes through the block
  char                     # => "f", "o"  <-- these are the results of two passes through the block
  ]                        # => [1, "f"], [2, "o"]  <-- these are the results of two passes through the block
}.join                     # => "1f2o"
end

encode('foo')  # => "1f2o"
```

And here's the second piece of code:

```
def encode(string)
  string                    # => "foobarbaz"
  .split( // )              # => ["f", "o", "o", "b", "a", "r", "b", "a", "z"]
  .sort                     # => ["a", "a", "b", "b", "f", "o", "o", "r", "z"]
  .join                     # => "aabbfoorz"
  .gsub(/(.)\1{2,}/) {|s| 
  s.length.to_s + 
  s[0,1] 
  }                         # => "aabbfoorz"
end

encode('foobarbaz')  # => "aabbfoorz"
```

Comment: Thank you! That plugin looks pretty cool too. Appreciate it

Comment: It is very cool, but currently seems to work with Sublime Text 2 only, otherwise it'll work with vim.